# MySQLdb installation issue on Mac. Required for MySQL connectivity with Django

Tags: python, mysql-python, libmysqlclient

I am creating a Django project on Mac. I want to use MySQL for database. I am trying to install MySQLdb which gives the following error:

```
(djangodev) $ pip3 install MySQL-python                                                                 

Collecting MySQL-python
  Using cached MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip (108 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [8 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/private/var/folders/9z/lf5bsw2929j34m5g6g9qcfqm0000gn/T/pip-install-5qv449ur/mysql-python_191252dd91f14deab09b6860c8c503d9/setup.py", line 13, in <module>
          from setup_posix import get_config
        File "/private/var/folders/9z/lf5bsw2929j34m5g6g9qcfqm0000gn/T/pip-install-5qv449ur/mysql-python_191252dd91f14deab09b6860c8c503d9/setup_posix.py", line 2, in <module>
          from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL-python being incompatible with Python 3. MySQL-python is only compatible with Python 2, as ConfigParser was renamed to configparser in Python 3.

To install mysqlclient, you can run the following command

```
pip3 install mysqlclient
```

Comment: I have already installed mysqlclient. But when I run Django server, it says to install mysqldb. Also I have been able to do so on my ubuntu installation, but not able to do it on mac

Comment: How about using Homebrew `brew install mysql`

Comment: Won't this be required for MySQL installation? I have successfully installed MySQL on my mac machine. Its the python connection module for Django that is causing problems

Comment: Glad you succeeded

Comment: No but the python module Mysqldb installation is still not working. That is the concern. So my issue remains unresolved